# jQuery UI tabs - remember last tab without cookies?

Tags: jquery, cookies, user-interface, tabs

So, I have a page using jQuery tabs. I've got it set up to remember the last tab selected using cookies. All is working fine, but there is some concern about the overhead using cookies.

We need to remember the last tab, even if someone went to a different page and came back.

Is there another solution to remember the last tab, apart from cookies, that will work well with jQuery UI tabs?  (ie, URL string query, hidden form fields?).  It seems the other "possible techniques" won't work if you leave the page and come back. Am I missing anything?

EDIT:
Per the below, I'm not concerned about the <50 byte cookie personally, but some others on the team are. It is a very busy site, with huge amounts of data, so any extra load always raises an eyebrow. I think the concern was that this cookie will get passed with every server request, even though it's only used/needed on one page in the whole site. The other option is to store it in our server side session I suppose, but is this really better (server impact-wise)?

Comment: There are sessions. Sessions/Cookies are basically the same, except one is server side and the other is client side.

Comment: "but there is some concern about the overhead using cookies"....please quantify this. Is your site so busy that you need to worry about a <50 byte cookie being passed around on each request?

Comment: sessions still use cookies, it is the only way to hack the lack of statefulness of http. notice that it's <50 bytes not kilobytes. it's really small.

Comment: Yeah, we do use sessions. And store a session uid cookie as well. Not sure if this needs to be saved in the server side session though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand from your question, you will need to persist the data somehow.. so that when user revisits the page,you can show him the last tab. Sessions are a good way to do it. And this info will only add a small memory footprint on the server side.